# Is the site directory in puppet 4.x required

Tags: installation, config, puppet

I'm following this site: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_full_example.html

In this file path:  /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/profile/manifests/jenkins/master.pp

Is the directory called 'site' required?
Could the directory called `profile` above be moved to the modules directory?

I'm using puppetserver version 4.10.12.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the directory called 'site' required? Could the directory called profile above be moved to the modules directory?

It depends.  In a general sense, sure, you can put your 'role' and 'profile' modules into the environment's `modules/` directory.  That's where I put mine.

But the writeup you linked explains why it demonstrates using a different directory:

> If you deploy your code with Puppet Enterprise’s code manager or r10k,
>   we recommend putting these two modules in your control repository
>   instead of declaring them in your Puppetfile. Since code manager and
>   r10k reserve the `modules` directory for their own use, you must put
>   them in a separate directory

If you are not using either of those code deployment tools and don't anticipate doing so any time soon -- like me -- then not only *can* you put your modules into the `modules/` directory, but that's what I would recommend doing.  But if you plan on using one of those then do follow the guide in this matter.